# How to print all expression evaluations and datatable manipulation results in R?

Tags: r, sas

So in SAS, there is an option to print (MLOGIC) out the result of each line executed and if a datatable was manipulated, it would print out the size of the table. Is there a way to do this in R without manually putting print statements everywhere?

So for example in SAS:

```
data temp;
 ~~ some functions, logic, etc ~~
run;
```

would display: datatable work.temp was created with X rows and Y observations

and in R: `temp <- ~~ data manipulation, etc ~~`
would also display: temp was created with X rows and Y Observations

Comment: This is not something that's build in to R. Maybe you want a package like [tidylog](https://github.com/elbersb/tidylog).

Comment: Is there a way to add a custom function that will print everytime a variable is created